# Unable to install a package

Tags: package, package-repositories

I am trying to add Magit to Emacs package list. 
I got as far as "Packages" menu and do not see how to add new, unlisted package. Is it even possible from Emacs ?

I even tried to "i-install"  highlighted package from the list but I have no idea WHERE to input it.

OK I got to Melpa and I am following the instructions to add new package to the list.. 
To add new package I have to do Alt -x  .... 
But **I do not know where in Emacs I am supposedly to put / type  this**  Alt x .... ( **see post title** )

I am getting this error and I have no clue what to call the form the error is displayed on. Sorry. 
.....
Importing package-keyring.gpg...done
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80 [2 times]
Beginning of buffer
command-execute: Buffer is read-only: #
**X is undefined**   after I type Alt -x 
C-c C-c is undefined

PS I have modified my original post - too big to put into  comments.

How do I update what has been successful so far and what is no longer an issue? Here ?

1. The error is no longer an issue
2. I know where the CLI goes - what is that area called ?
3. No need to type "i" on package to be installed - after highlighting it there is pretty intuitive GUI to follow.
4. I am missing plain Ctrl C / V , pity.

Comment: IIUC, you have set up the package system and you have done `M-x package-list-packages` or clicked on `Options/Manage Emacs P{ackages`, so you are looking at a (long) list of packages.  Correct? If so, you navigate to the package that you want, mark it for installation with `i` (emacs puts a capital `I` next to that package to show that it is marked) and then you say `x` to carry out the installation (you can mark more than one package and install them all with an `x`). If I've misunderstood, please edit the question and add more detail about what you are doing: the more detail the better...

Comment: Sorry , but you did misunderstood my post.The package Magit is not on the list. I have to add it to the list first. I am asking if that is even possible within Emacs. Or how to do it. The tutorials are not that clear for adding new packages to the list.

Comment: Welcome!! The default package manager is great for long time users, but may not  be as intuitive if you're used to other package managers. To see magit you'll need to add `https://melpa.org/packages/` to your `package-archives` variable. In emacs, type `M-x customize-variable RET` then type `package-archives RET`. The `M-x` means press `Meta`, `Alt` or `Esc` key and `x` at same time. The `RET` is the `return` or `enter` key. You'll see an `[INS]` button which is how you get a new section for melpa. After adding click `[Apply and Save]`. Then do `M-x package-initialize RET` and you'll see magit

Comment: OK back to start After I do ATL-X I get this error. AT the end of this copy. Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/50git-core.el (source)...done
For information about GNU Emacs and the GNU system, type C-h C-a.
Importing package-keyring.gpg...done
Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80 [2 times]
Beginning of buffer
command-execute: Buffer is read-only: #<buffer *Messages*>
X is undefined
C-c C-c is undefined

Comment: I think I got it. One more silly question - how do I terminate after Alt-x is running ? I need to start over to do screen shots for my log  records.

Comment: OK added Magit package and followed install process  until I run into "emacs 25.1 not available" When I clicked on it it said "build-in" . I assume then no installation required. How do I recover? I do not wnat to start "install" over again utill I know ow to handle this "emacs 25.1 "

Comment: What you call "the CLI" is called minibuffer.

Comment: So is " buffer " synonymous with  "form / window/ dialog " ? So what do you call the feedback / responses  -  "results buffer"? Perhaps there is a "dictionary of terms " published somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to emacs.SE! Concerning the vocabulary, I suggest you read  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Screen.html#Screen